# Bootstrap Tooltips (Not Working - JS implemented)

Tags: tooltip

I have read the other questions on this topic, which seem to all be based around not implementing the JS.

I have all the required scripts:

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Implemented the JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
</script>
```

My Html

```
<a  class='hasTooltip' data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!" href="index.php">Home</a>
```

And yet my tooltips are the standard tooltips and not the bootstrap ones. I'm using Chrome, but I can see the examples on w3schools. Any ideas?

Comment: whats your html look like?

Comment: <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This is a Tooltip">Hello</a>

Comment: Edit:: I looked a the console and it says 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function'

Comment: just for your sanity if your still trying to figure this out. The code you provided should work 100% perfect. If it's not working then it has to do with something else (your environment, your version of javascript, or where you load your javascript...).